# Prime numbers code

Tags: c#

Why isn't this code working? It should bring me all the primes to 10 but instead I get the numbers 2 and 3 only.

```
bool m = true;
int i;
int a;
for (a = 2; a <= 10; a++)
{
    for (i = 2; i < a; i++) 
    {
        if (a % i == 0)
        {
            m = false;
        }
    }

    if (m == true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: How about to be nice to SO community and format your question?

Comment: maybe because ``m`` is false for the rest of the iterations right after ``a == 3``.... next time try a debugger, they do a really good job at this kind of questions.

Comment: Please chose good names for your variables. One letter is rarely enough to describe meaning... (except maybe `i`)... And avoid "thank you notes" and tags in title.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code?  Set a breakpoint and see what happens when `a == 5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (a = 2; a <= 10; a++)
{
    for (i = 2; i < a; i++)
    {
        if (a % i == 0)
        {
            m = false;
        }
    }

    if (m == true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }

    m = true; //<<******* Add this line
}
```

of course some speed up is always possible

```
for (a = 2; a <= 100; a++)
{
    for (i = 2; i < Math.Sqrt(a); i++) //<--- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number#Trial_division
    {
        if (a % i == 0)
        {
            m = false;
            break; //<---- a is not prime, quit the inner loop immediately.
        }
    }

    if (m == true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }

    m = true; //<<******* Add this line
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Two major issues.

1. You never reset `m` so once you find a non prime you are stuck with that result for the rest of your iterations.
2. When you are testing for a non prime you just keep on going onece you found one and you overwrite your result. Due to how you wrote it, its not that big of a problem as `i-1 % i` will never be `== 0`, but you could save your self a lot of time if you broke out early. (you can also save yourself a lot of time by testing up to `Math.Sqrt(a)` because after that point every eligible divisor would have been already tested (`a / i = b` is the same as `a / b = i` so you only need to check one of them) )

Comment: Good approach. While having more upvotes, collecting the best parts of other answers to ensure to be *accepted* ...

Answer (score 0):

You're not resetting `m` after you've passed a non-prime.

Answer (score -1):

Do you really need a boolean variable? If all you need to do is print the values, then you can skip the boolean:

```
int i;
int a;
for(a=2; a<=10; a++) {
    for(i=2; i<a; i++) {
        if(a % i == 0) {
            Console.WriteLine(a);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that the `break` forces the exit of the inner `for`, so you can go on with the next iteration of the outer `for`.

---

Correcting: The above code prints the *non-prime* numbers. So yes, you may need the boolean variable to track the prime numbers. But you have to break the inner for if you want it to work properly:

```
int i;
int a;
bool m;
for(a=2; a<=10; a++) {
    m = true
    for(i=2; i<a; i++) {
        if(a % i == 0) {
            m = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (m) {
        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
}
```

Of course, you can get the same result without the boolean variable, just performing another comparison after the break:

```
int i;
int a;
for(a=2; a<=10; a++) {
    for(i=2; i<a; i++) {
        if(a % i == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if(a % i != 0) {
        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just run your code and see the reason.

Comment: @I4V got it. thank you. I've corrected the code

Comment: Barranka, why do you post answers without validating them. your 2nd answer(`Of course, you can get the same result without the boolean variable`) doesn't work either. (I ignore the syntax error in the first one)